Received transaction details with status 200
Received transaction details with status 200.
keep getting this
Solana RPC URL
url = 'https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com
any solution to this or any limitations i am not aware about please someone help

This is the public RPC endpoint, it free for all and for that not advisable to use on a production setting because of the many limitations imposed on it.

Maximum number of requests per 10 seconds per IP: 100


Maximum number of requests per 10 seconds per IP for a single RPC: 40


Maximum concurrent connections per IP: 40


Maximum connection rate per 10 seconds per IP: 40
Maximum amount of data per 30 second: 100 MB

ref: https://solana.com/docs/core/clusters#mainnet-beta-rate-limits
You're better of using a private RPC provider like Triton or chainstack
More private providers list:  https://solana.com/rpc
